# naming a dynamic number of form inputs incrementally

Tags: php, html, forms

I generate a dynamic quantity of form inputs, based on a user-submitted number (`$transponum`).
I use `str_repeat` to build a string containing the desired number of inputs.

But I'm having trouble naming the inputs. I need:

```
<input type="text" name="transpo(a number that increases every repeat)" />
```

How can I achieve that with PHP?

Here is my code:

```
<form id="form" name="form" method="post" action="step8.php" role="form"> 
    <div class="form-group"><?php
        $a = 1;

        $str.= "<label class=\"control-label\" for=\"exampleInputEmail1\">Name</label>";
        $str.= "<input style=\"width: 60%;\" type=\"text\" class=\"form-control\" id=\"transponum\" name=\"transponame".$a."\" placeholder=\"Name\">";
        $str.= "<label class=\"control-label\" for=\"exampleInputEmail1\">ID</label>";
        $str.= "<input style=\"width: 60%;\" type=\"text\" class=\"form-control\" id=\"transponum\" name=\"transpoid".$a."\" placeholder=\"Name\"><hr>"; 
        $str.= $a = $a+1;

        echo str_repeat($str, $transponum);

    ?></div>                                             
    <button type="submit" class="btn-success btn" name="submit">Next</button>                                             
</form>
```

Comment: Does $a === 1 on every form field?

Comment: Yes, form name="transponame1" and "transpoid1" on every repeated form input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have several suggestions, detailed below:

### Use a loop

Use a [for loop](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) rather than `str_repeat`.
Use the loop to increment your `$a` variable from 1 to `$transponum`.

```php
for ($a=1;$a<=$transponum;$a++) { ... }
```

### Post as arrays

Name your inputs so that they post as arrays. That way, you don't need to dynamically build the input names.

```html
<input name="names[]" />
<input name="ids[]" />
```

> Notice the square brackets after the variable name, that's what makes it an array. You can group the elements into different arrays by assigning the same name to different elements.
>   -- [FAQ @ php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays)

Then, you'll end up with a `$_POST` array like this:

```
Array
(
    [names] => Array
               (
                   [0] => 'name 1',
                   [1] => 'name 2',
                   [2] => 'name 3',
                   ...
               ),
    [ids] =>   Array
               (
                   [0] => 'id 1',
                   [1] => 'id 2',
                   [2] => 'id 3',
                   ...
               )
)
```

### Remove duplicated IDs

Element IDs must be unique. Associate labels with inputs implicitly by placing the `<input>` elements inside their respective `<label>` elements. Then you can remove the duplicated IDs.

> To associate a label with another control implicitly, the control element must be within the contents of the LABEL element. -- [forms @ w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#edef-LABEL)

```
<label>Name: <input /></label>
```

Also see this [simple label example at developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label#Simple_label_example), for reference.

---

### Complete Example

Here's an example that includes all of my suggestions:

```php
<form id="form" name="form" method="post" action="step8.php" role="form"> 
    <div class="form-group"> <?php

        for ($a=1;$a<=$transponum;$a++) {

            ?><label>
                <span>Name</span>
                <input type="text" name="transponame[<?=$a?>]" placeholder="Name">
            </label>
            <label>
                <span>ID</span>
                <input type="text" name="transpoid[<?=$a?>]" placeholder="Name">
            </label>
            <hr><?php

        }

    ?></div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn-success btn" name="submit">Next</button>                                             
</form>
```

---

### Edit:

Note that specifying the `$a` value in input names is probably not necessary. In your context, empty brackets will work just as well:

```html
<input type="text" name="transponame[]" placeholder="Name">
```

> Specifying array keys is optional in HTML. If you do not specify the keys, the array gets filled in the order the elements appear in the form. -- [FAQ @ php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays)

Comment: This is it! I spent all day trying to figure this out by some sort of mathematical  equation!! Such a fast reponse, wow! Thank you, and stack overflow must be where it's at! Also, thank you for the additional information! Not expected but gratefully accepted!

Answer (score 0):

To add to `showdev`'s answer.

You cannot use `str_repeat` to achieve what you have in mind. `str_repeat` literally repeats a string. See the [documentation page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-repeat.php).

In your case, you have to use either a loop or create array type input names.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't use duplicate Ids

```
<form id="form" name="form" method="post" action="step8.php" role="form"> 
<div class="form-group">
<?php for($i=0;$i<transponum;$i++){ ?>
<label class="control-label" for="exampleInputEmail1">Name</label>";
<input style="width: 60%;" type="text" class="form-control" id="transponum" name="transponame<?php echo $i;?>" placeholder="Name">
<label class="control-label" for="exampleInputEmail1">ID</label>
<input style="width: 60%;" type="text" class="form-control" id="transponumLabel" name="transpoid<?php echo $i;?>" placeholder="Name"><hr>
<?php } ?>
</div>                                             
<button type="submit" class="btn-success btn" name="submit">Next</button>                                             
</form>
```